# Best way to tranverse List in Java?

Tags: java, performance, synchronization

I have a concurrent List used in multi-threaded environment. Once the List is built, mostly operation is traversing it. I am wondering which of the following 2 methods are more efficient, or what's cost of creating a new List vs using synchronized? Or maybe there are other better ways?

```
List<Object> list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Object>();

public int[] getAllValue1() {
    List<Object> list2 = new ArrayList<Object>(list);
    int[] data = new int[list2.size()];
    int i = 0;
    for (Object obj : list2) {
        data[i++] = obj.getValue();
    }
    return data;
}

public int[] getAllValue2() {
    synchronized (list) {
        int[] data = new int[list.size()];
        int i = 0;
        for (Object obj : list) {
            data[i++] = obj.getValue();
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
getAllValue1(): It is threadsafe, because it takes a snapshot of the CopyOnWriteList, which itself is threadsafe List. However, as sharakan points out, the cost is iterate 2 lists, and creating a local object ArrayList, which could be costly if the original list is large.

getAllValue2(): It is also threadsafe in the synchronization block. (Assume other functions do synchronization properly.) The reason to put it in the synchronization block is because I want to pre-allocate the array, to make sure .size() call is synchronized with iteration. (Iteration part is threadsafe, because it use CopyOnWriteList.) However the cost here is the opportunity cost of using syncrhonized block. If there are 1 million clients calling getAllValue2(), each one has to wait.

So I guess the answer really depends on how many concurrent users need to read the data. If not many concurrent users, probably the method2 is better. Otherwise, method1 is better. Agree?

In my usage, I have a couple concurrent clients, probably method2 is preferred. (BTW, my list is about 10k size).

Comment: But does anybody write on the list? Furthermore, Object has no getValue() method. This isn't the code you are actually running. Give us more :)

Comment: How is the list being populated ? Is the code populating the list, synchronized ?

Comment: I skip the initialization part. Once the List is initialized, it stays in memory. Occasionally, there will be additions to to the list.

Comment: The object is big value class, and contains a lot fields, like a very wide table in the database. To some users, they want to get a colume of integers from the table, which is what I am trying to do here. Since it's must be threadsafe, so I used CopyOnWriteList. But when traversing the list, and returning the int[], I still need to make additional efforts to make it threadsafe. I think both functions are threadsafe traversing, correct me if I am wrong here.

Comment: @gd1 I believe the line in getAllValue1() you're referring to will happen consistently and in a thread safe manner, because he's using a `CopyOnWriteArrayList`

Comment: I think if it's possible ***at all***, you should change your API so it doesn't return an array.  Then you can use a variant of method 1 with a single traversal, and no locking.

Comment: Question: you mentioned that the writers will be adding elements to the list.  Do they only add elements to the end (ie, is this actually a queue?)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** (again): 
Since you are using a copy on write array list (should've been more observant) I would get the iterator and use that to initialize your array. Since the iterator is a snapshot of the array at the time you ask for it you can synchronize on the list to get the size and then subsequently iterate without fear of `ConcurrentModificationException` or having the iterator change.

```
public int[] getAllValue1() {
    synchronized(list){
        int[] data = new int[list.size()];            
    }
    Iterator i = list.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()){
        data[i++] = i.next().getValue();
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: CopyOnWriteList is threadsafe List, so the Iteration is threadsafe. However, I need to allocate the size of an array, which needs to be syncrhonized with the iteration in getValue2().

Answer (score 0):

getAllValue1 looks good given that you need to return an array of primitive types based on a a field of your objects.  It'll be two iterations, but consistent and you won't cause any contention between reader threads.  You haven't posted any profiling results, but unless your list is quite large I'd be more worried about contention in a multithreaded environment than the cost of two complete iterations.

You could remove one iteration if you change the API.  Easiest way to do that is to return a Collection instead, as follows:

```
public Collection<Integer> getAllValue1() {
    List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(list.size());
    for (Object obj : list2) {
        list2.add(obj.getValue());
    }
    return list2;
}
```

if you can change your API that way, that'd be an improvement.

Answer (score 0):

I think the second one is more efficient. The reason is, in the first one, you create another list as a local creation. That means if the original list contains lot of data, it is gonna copy all of them. If it contains millions of data, then it will be a issue.

However, there is `list.toArray()` method

Collections interface also contain some useful stuff

```
  Collection synchronizedCollection = Collections.synchronizedCollection(list);
```

or

```
List synchronizedList = Collections.synchronizedList(list);
```

If you need objects VALUE, and not object, then move with the second code of yours. Else, you can replace appropriate parts of the second code with the above functions, and do whatever you want.